# ionic/cordova error code 1, error building one of platforms

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

Ok i have installed:

nodejs  v 5.4.0 (latest)

ant     v 1.9.6 (latest)

java    v 1.8.0_71 (latest)

git     v 2.7.0 (latest)

ionic   v 1.7.14 (latest)

corodva v 6.0.0 (latest)

here is my env variable looks like:
ANT_HOME,JAVA_HOME,ANDROID_HOME variable
[image]

my PATH variable
[image]

im running on windows 10 64bit, but i keep getting errors both from ionic build and cordova build, here are the log of the error (i get the same build error with cordova ):

```
ionic build
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\work\boaz\myapp\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js C:\work\boaz\myapp
add to body class: platform-android
add to body class: platform-ios
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65
Unzipping C:\Users\boaz\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.2.1-all\2m8005s69iu8v0oiejfej094b\gradle-2.2.1-all.zip to C:\Users\boaz\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.2.1-all\2m8005s69iu8v0oiejfej094bException in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:78)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:163)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:160)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$400(Install.java:29)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:70)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
        ... 3 more

ERROR building one of the platforms: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,"C:\work\boaz\myapp\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\work\boaz\myapp\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,"C:\work\boaz\myapp\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\work\boaz\myapp\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solved!

I deleted the .gradle folder under C:\Users(user-name)\.gradle

rerun

```
ionic build
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Works I just removed the .gradle from "C:\Users\name" folder and on the console I ran $ cordova run --devices on git bash and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you're installing only the neccessary sdk tools by hand like me, this did the trick for me:

```
android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "extra-android-m2repository"
```