# Error building Cordova apk

Tags: android, cordova, build, apk, phonegap-build

I'm new to Cordova, I can run my code in the browser using `cordova run browser` but I would like to turn it into an apk so I can run it on my phone and really test it.

The developer I am working with sends me apk all the time built from the same files whenever he has an update on the project, however when I want to make minor changes myself I can't create an apk to test them because it throws an error.

```
cordova build android --release
```

> Error: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,"X:\Websites\AppAndroid\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b X:\Websites\AppAndroid\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"

It also says this but I can't make sense of it with my limited knowledge

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I have tried some other solutions from other questions and YouTube videos such as setting my paths to JAVA and ANDROID_HOME but these didn't help my issue.

The read out also makes a suggestion, I tried this but it doesn't tell me anything extra in a log or fix the issue:

> Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with
>   --info or --debug option to get more log output.

***UPDATE***

I am wondering if it is my JAVA_HOME path.

That is set to 1.7.0_79

> ANDROID_HOME=C:\User\Me\AppData\Local\Android\sdk JAVA_HOME=C:\Program
>   Files\java\jdk1.7.0_79

But when I do `java -version` I get this 1.8.0_121:

> java version "1.8.0_121" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.8.0_121-b13) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

That's 2 different versions, but when I change JAVA_HOME in the environments window, it doesn't change JAVA_HOME that is displayed when I try to build the apk.

So I am unable to correct it to see if it fixes the error :\

Comment: Try doing [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35230530/7303349), but replace ionic build with cordova build, report back

Comment: @SimonVisserIit That gave the same output - except it installed gradle first, the same error output :S

Answer (score 0):

I had configured JAVA_HOME wrong in my Environment Variables settings.

It was out of date compared to the Java I had installed.

Then when I tried to change it, I realised I didn't have the JDK installed, I only had JRE (Java Runtime Environment).

So I Googled javascript development kit download and was taken to the website and downloaded the JDK, then correctly set my paths in the Environment Variables settings to represent JDK not JRE.

I closed console and ran it all again and success, built!